# Single authentication for two different Asp.net websites with two different domain and databases

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have two different Asp.Net web apps on two different domains with two different databases which are not linked with each other. There users are managed in two different databases. 
Our requirement is when a user gets login on first website and open the second website it gets automatically login on the second website.

Comment: Uh, you've not even asked a question.

Comment: how you will make sure that a user registered on one website is also registered on the other?

Comment: @Farkie Requirement asked in the question is the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two websites **www.foo.com** and **www.bar.com** , this can be done by using the cookies but i don't think there is a way to read cross-domain cookies

But you can create a third website **www.foba.com** and these two websites will be calling this third website for the authentication of cookie. use this authenticated cookie and allow user to have seamless browsing across both websites

**Ex**: **Forums.asp.net** and **Hotmail** works like this by using the **live.microsoft.com** to set the authentication cookie.

[Please Refer this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic)

Comment: he says the users are managed in two different databases, then how he will authenticate from third common website?

Comment: @WaqasRaja for Creation of Cookie for two website it doesn't have any link with their  own database.

Comment: Suppose user `A` is registered on `Site1` but not on `Site2` then the common website will reply on which database, Database for Site` or Database for Site2?

Comment: @WaqasRaja  when you try to open the site2 on new tab, and assuming that you have logged in with site1 now when you try to reload the site2, there the thirdsite will autenticate the user (Please keep in mind i am speaking only authentication not the authorization)

Comment: @Webruster  : Isn't third website requires users information when we call it for authentication. In the link you mentioned they are managing are users information(Username and password) on the third website.

Comment: @KhurramRaftaz we are taking only Autentication , suppose with website `A` u tried to login with credentials, then Cookie autentication of third site will be applied to it  , when you tried to Login with `B`  as you gonna redirect to the same thrid website and you will be using the  cookie and he authenticated pages for the client sites (that are currently requested by the browser) are served to the browser, and if not found, the user is redirected to the login page of the corresponding site.